# seaborn despine overrides font settings in matplotlib in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

the `despine` function in seaborn library appears to override font settings arguments in matplotlib. example:

```
plt.figure()
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
plt.xticks([1,2,3], fontsize=13)
# despine blocks xtick labels font size
sns.despine(trim=True, offset=2)
plt.show()
```

if I comment out the `sns.despine(trim=True, offset=2)` line then the `fontsize` argument to `plt.xticks` works. how can I use `despine` without having it override my fontsize settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky problem I encountered when adding the spine trim/offsetting functionality to seaborn. You can see my original question here:

[Efficiently cache and restore matplotlib axes parameters after moving spines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21541295/efficiently-cache-and-restore-matplotlib-axes-parameters-after-moving-spines)

The solution we came up with, after some help from the MPL mailing list is here:
https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blob/dfdd1126626f7ed0fe3737528edecb71346e9eb0/seaborn/utils.py#L288

Looks like this is an edge-case that our work-around misses.

As a work-around for you, I recommend the despining/offsetting before formatting the ticks:

```
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import pyplot
import seaborn

fig, ax = pyplot.subplots()
# despine blocks xtick labels font size
seaborn.despine(trim=True, offset=2)

x = [1, 2, 3]
ax.plot(x, x)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(x, fontsize=13)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the xtick font size using `rcParams`:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
plt.figure()
mpl.rcParams['xtick.labelsize'] = 13 # must be place before the actual plot creation
plt.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
# despine blocks xtick labels font size
sns.despine(trim=True, offset=2)
plt.show()
```

This should work and still correctly apply `despine`.

Comment: I don't think this will work because the x axis won't be appropriately trimmed.

Comment: Please see my updated answer. This should work correctly.